# I can't trigger ANTLR rule

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr, antlr4, pcre

I'm trying to build a PCRE engine, and I'm using [this ANTLR grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/pcre/PCRE.g4). These are some of its rules:

```
octal_char
 : ( Backslash (D0 | D1 | D2 | D3) octal_digit octal_digit
   | Backslash octal_digit octal_digit
   )

 ;

octal_digit
 : D0 | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 | D6 | D7
 ;

digit
 : D0 | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 | D6 | D7 | D8 | D9 // just '0','1','2','3',...,'9'
 ;
```

When I try triggering the `octal_char` rule with strings like `\075`, it simply doesn't work, and I don't understand why.

Example parse tree for the string `\075`:

```
parse
  alternation
    expr
      element
        atom
          shared_atom \0
      element
        atom
          literal
            shared_literal
              digit 7
      element
        atom
          literal
            shared_literal
              digit 5
  <EOF>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `atom` rule, move the `backreference` up. So instead of:

```
atom
 : ...
 | backreference
 | ...
 ;
```

do:

```
atom
 : backreference
 | ...
 ;
```

FYI: note that the grammar you're using is based on the document http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt from 10 January 2012. The current revision is from 14 June 2021, so there are quite some changes not yet accounted for in that ANTLR grammar you're using.

### Edit

I just updated the grammar and made a PR: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/pull/3690 (original repo with better test cases can be found here: https://github.com/bkiers/pcre-parser)

Answer (score 1):

The `shared_atom` rule precedes the `literal` rule in the `atom` rule.

Knowing nothing of the intent of the language, I can't tell if that's an error or not, but that's what catching the `\0`.

Depending on the intended semantics, you may need to reorder those rule references, modify lookahead, and/or use syntactic predicates to fix this.

Swapping the order of the two rule refs will get the octal to match, but may cause other things that `shared_atom` should match to get caught by `literal` and possibly fail.